# while inserting data through proccedure facing unexpected issues

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have created procedure to insert data into my table 
Test :

```
CREATE TABLE TEST
(
Id INT, 
Name VARCHAR(5)
)

CREATE PROCEDURE usp_insert
(
@i_id INT,
@vc_name VARCHAR(10)
)
AS 
BEGIN 
BEGIN TRANSACTION  
SET NOCOUNT ON ;  

BEGIN TRY 
DECLARE  @new_identity INT; 
INSERT INTO dbo.Test
        (Id,
        name)
VALUES 
(@i_id,
@vc_name)
    SELECT @new_identity = SCOPE_IDENTITY()  

    SELECT @new_identity   

    RETURN(@new_identity)  
    COMMIT TRANSACTION 
COMMIT TRAN
END TRY 
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber  
     ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity  
     ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState  
     ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure  
     ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine  
     ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;  
     ROLLBACK TRANSACTION  

END CATCH
END
```

while inserting data i'm getting error as below like

**EXEC usp_insert 1,'mohan'**

```
The 'usp_insert' procedure attempted to return a status of NULL, which is not allowed. A status of 0 will be returned instead.
Msg 266, Level 16, State 2, Procedure usp_insert, Line 0
Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 0, current count = 1.
```

but data is inserting 
and

trying to insert more length name to see exception it is deleting before data and in second attempt it is showing Exception

**EXEC usp_insert 1,'mohankumar'**

```
Msg 266, Level 16, State 2, Procedure usp_insert, Line 0
Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0.
```

Comment: you have 2 `begin tran` and only `one commit`. also don't use return to return identity values created. use `SELECT` or output variable. additionally you return before committing the transaction

Comment: is your `Id` field identity or not? you initial question had it as identity and the latest edit does not. `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` doesnt make sense if the table does not have an identity column

Comment: you have two commits in your statement? is that your intention?

Answer (score 2):

When you call

```
EXEC usp_insert 1,'mohankumar'
```

> The 'usp_insert' procedure attempted to return a status of NULL, which is not allowed. A status of 0 will be returned instead.
>
> Msg 266, Level 16, State 2, Procedure usp_insert, Line 0
>   Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 0, current count = 1.

You get a warning, because your table `TEST` does not have an `identity` column hence `SELECT @new_identity = SCOPE_IDENTITY()` will always set `@new_identity` as `NULL` and since `@new_identity` is returned, you get the warning from Sql Server.

You get the error for transaction count because the procedure exists on the control reaching the `RETURN` statement and `COMMIT TRANSACTION` is not executed. Hence there is a mismatch of transaction count before and after the execution of the procedure.

You may think that the procedure has saved the data however that is not the case because the transaction is still open and if you issue a `ROLLBACK` the data will be rolled back. try checking the data in the table from another session and you'll get blocked while trying to access the table.

On your Second call

```
EXEC usp_insert 1,'mohankumar'
```

> Msg 266, Level 16, State 2, Procedure usp_insert, Line 0
>   Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0.

The previous transaction is already open and since the parameter has higher length than the new row, insert fails and the flow moves to catch block where the transaction is rolled back.

This is the transaction started by the first call to `usp_insert` that is it looks like the second call removed the data of the previous insert however the insert was never committed.

**The way forward**

1. If you want to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`, your table should have an `IDENTITY` column. If you have an identity column in the table, then you don't need to pass a variable to your procedure for an identity column
2. Do not use `RETURN` as a way to return data(or the id inserted) to the application. use `SELECT` or an `OUTPUT` parameter.
3. `RETURN` should be the last statement in your `BEGIN TRY`(unless you have conditional checks). any `COMMIT` / `ROLLBACK` / business logic should be before `RETURN`
4. Do not return the error message as a `SELECT`. `ROLLBACK` your transaction, log it (if needed) and then throw it back to the application and let the application handle the error

**Updated Procedure**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_insert
(
@i_id INT,
@vc_name VARCHAR(10)
)
AS 
BEGIN 
SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN TRY 

INSERT INTO dbo.Test(Id,name)
VALUES(@i_id,@vc_name)

END TRY 
BEGIN CATCH
    INSERT Into LogTable
    SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber  
     ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity  
     ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState  
     ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure  
     ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine  
     ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage; 

    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

    THROW; -- You can use RAISERROR if your sql server version doesn't support THROW

END CATCH
END
```

Note:

1. Removed `BEGIN TRAN` and `COMMIT` because it's just a single DML statement and explicit transaction boundary is not required for the current code.
2. Removed the use of `RETURN` since you already know the id you are trying to save.
3. Log the error messages in a table if required, else just throw them back to the calling application

Comment: can you please suggest me the best way by remodifying this Insert Procedure

Answer (score 0):

A better way of writing the same functionality is :

```
CREATE TABLE TEST
(
Id INT IDENTITY (1,1), -- declare Identity property to auto-increment Id 
Name VARCHAR(5)
)
Go

CREATE PROCEDURE usp_insert
@vc_name VARCHAR(10),
@new_identity Int OUTPUT -- Explicitly declare the returned value
AS 
BEGIN 
BEGIN TRANSACTION  
SET NOCOUNT ON ; 

        BEGIN TRY               
                INSERT INTO Test
                        (name)
                VALUES 
                (@vc_name)
                SELECT @new_identity = SCOPE_IDENTITY()  

                SELECT @new_identity   
                COMMIT TRANSACTION
                RETURN(@new_identity)  

                --COMMIT TRAN -- where is this coming from?
        END TRY 
        BEGIN CATCH
            SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber  
             ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity  
             ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState  
             ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure  
             ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine  
             ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;  
             ROLLBACK TRANSACTION  

        END CATCH
END

GO-- Declare the variable to receive the output value of the procedure.
DECLARE @Id Int;
-- Execute the procedure specifying a name for the input parameter
-- and saving the output value in the variable @Id
EXECUTE usp_insert
    'Mohan', @new_identity = @Id OUTPUT;
-- Display the value returned by the procedure.
PRINT 'New Id for this employee is ' + 
    convert(varchar(10),@Id);
GO
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/23468/2)</kbd>

Comment: you are still committing the transaction after `RETURN(@new_identity)`  which is wrong not to mention using `RETURN` as a way to return inserted data is discouraged

Comment: my table doesn't have identity i won't able to modify now it have already data so can you please tell me how to proceed